# Issue with Calling "playAudio" Function from Multiple TouchableOpacity Elements in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm encountering an issue while trying to call the playAudio function from multiple TouchableOpacity elements in a React Native application. I have a component named Grade1AppleExercises that contains a list of touchable boxes. Each box is associated with a specific audio file that needs to be played when the box is pressed. However, despite my efforts, the audio isn't playing as expected. Below is the relevant code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Sound from 'react-native-sound';
import { useLanguage } from '../../../LanguageContext';

const Grade1AppleExercises = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const { selectedLanguage } = useLanguage();

  const appleAddQ = {
    en: require('../../../assets/audio/english/add3apples.mp3'),
    ur: require('../../../assets/audio/urdu/add3applesquiz.mp3'),
  };

  const appleSubQ = {
    en: require('../../../assets/audio/english/sub3apples.mp3'),
    ur: require('../../../assets/audio/urdu/sub3apples.mp3'),
  };

  const [audio, setAudio] = useState(null);

  const playAudio = (audioFile) => {
    if (audio) {
      audio.release();
    }
    setAudio(new Sound(audioFile));
    if (audio) {
      audio.play();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.row}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Addition Q No 1 : Apple Grade 1');
            playAudio(appleAddQ[selectedLanguage]);
          }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imageStyle}
            source={require('../../../assets/images/Addition.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Addition </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.box}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate('Addition Q No 1 : Orange Grade 1');
            playAudio(appleSubQ[selectedLanguage]);
          }}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imageStyle}
            source={require('../../../assets/images/Addition.png')}
          />
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}> Addition (Orange) </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Grade1AppleExercises;
```

I've confirmed that the audio files are correctly loaded based on the selected language. However, when I press the boxes, the audio doesn't play as intended. I suspect there might be a problem with how I'm managing the audio state or releasing the previous audio instance. Can someone please guide me on what could be causing this issue and suggest a solution to ensure the playAudio function works correctly when called from multiple TouchableOpacity elements?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!